# Java constructors for side-effects only

Tags: java

I have a Java instance class, "ResultMaker" that exists for side-effects only (sending an email) and the object is never subsequently used.  (Of course this could be re-written so that ResultMaker is a static class, but when I add "flesh" to the class, adding methods and making multiple instances, I think I would eventually want to have a reference to the object, so my justification for declaring ResultMaker as an instance class at this stage is that the code is not finished yet.)

In order to clean up a Java warning that `r` was unused (see the short example code), I removed the assignment to variable `r` (see code) so I was left with only a `new ResultMaker(ans)`.  The side-effect stopped happening with the code change so I guess instantiation of ResultMaker no longer happens.  Is this deserving of a compiler warning (that there will be no instantiation) or is this a well-known aspect of Java?

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        Thing tt = new Thing();
        String answer = tt.DoSomething();

        ResultMaker r = new ResultMaker(answer);

        resp.getWriter().println(answer);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you aren't really seeing what you think you're seeing. I *very* much doubt that the constructor call was removed. If you could provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would help - but I suspect you'll find that it was some other change - possibly to how you *observe* the side-effect - that happened.

I would strongly encourage you to make this a static method which describes the side-effects you're expecting though - a constructor call which doesn't actually use the result is odd, and I wouldn't be surprised to see a maintainer remove the call *expecting* it to be a no-op. The purpose of a constructor *ought* to be to construct an object, not for side-effects.

EDIT: If your code is *actually* like that, then the *first* thing I'd do is change these empty exception blocks:

```
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
}
catch (AddressException e) 
{
} 
catch (MessagingException e) 
{
}
```

At the *very least* these should log what's gone wrong.

For investigative purposes I'd also add logging before and after the constructor call, and within the constructor. That should help show how the execution is actually flowing.

Comment: Jon, you were right.  Constructors purely for side-effects do work but the indeterminacy of GAE led me to attribute the problem to the code change involving the constructor.

Comment: For completeness: the indeterminacy had to do with GAE's Queue.purge invocation (not shown).  It runs asynchronously and takes an indeterminate while.

Answer (score 1):

Since the action of sending an email is pretty much stateless, you can add a method to the `ResultMaker` class (`MailSender`?), something along the lines of `r.sendMail(content)`. If you are using Spring or Guice, you can create a singleton and inject it throughout the application. A poor man's solution would be put a `ResultMaker` instance in the `ServletContext` when the application starts and re-use the same instance for all requests.

Comment: +1 - though if you share / reuse a `ResultMaker` instance via the ServletContext you 1) need to make it thread-safe, and 2) need to worry that it might become a bottleneck.

Comment: @Stephen: Indeed, but as mentioned: 1) sending a mail is almost always stateless, if not then it really shouldn't be used the way OP is using it 2) Good point; I'd either post the mail request to a persistent job queue or simply use a ExecutorService to make sure the request handling thread doesn't block. :-)